# How to create table like avro?

Tags: hive, avro, parquet

I created a table (test_load) based on the schema of another one (test). Then i inserted test_load into another table.

```
drop table if exists test_load;
create external table test_load
like test
location /test_load_folder;

insert into warehouse
select * from test_load;
```

It works fine when everything is in parquet.
I then evolved my test schema to avro and recreated my test_load table but when i try to insert into warehouse i receive an error :

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 
from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

I'm looking for the good syntax to re-create the load table and scpecify its avro. My hypothesis is that hive still considers its parquet files.

I tried

```
drop table if exists test_load;
create external table test_load
like test
location /test_load_folder
stored as avro;
```

but i have a syntax error.

Comment: The `stored as avro` part needs to just after the table name: `create external table test_load stored as avro like ...`

Comment: Thank you! it's the right syntax. the inserttion bug was somewhere else. A hdfs problem.